# How to iterate efficiently thru json object and then filter based on input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have my data in *MongoDB* database, below is the format. I have searched for streams like the functionality we have in Java, but couldn't find one.

Data from DB:

```
[
    {
        "eventList": [
            {
                "eventId": "1,2,3",
                "eventType": "1"
            },
            {
                "eventId": "4,5,6",
                "eventType": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "eventList": [
            {
                "eventId": "7,8,9",
                "eventType": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Input to the service:

```
{
    "eventId": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```

We have to loop thru input and match the eventId from the db list. The JSON payload has 60,000 lines. When I use a traditional for loop it takes 23 seconds when I give 20 events in the input. I might have made some mistakes. There might be the best way to handle this. I have three for loops one for the input iteration, one for iterating the event list which is an array and the last loop for comparison to check if the eventId matches.

Hope all my statement covers

My code I tried.

```
for (let i = 0; i < request.eventId.length; i++) {
    let eventId = request.eventId[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < response[j].eventList.length) {
            if (response[j].eventList[k].eventId.includes(eventId)) {
                console.log("matches");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @Bergi I just updated the code. Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Uh, yes, that's very inefficient. What are you going to do with the matches other than to log them?

Comment: You say there is a database, are you really storing a JSON blob in your database?

Comment: So if the eventId matches then I have to send in the response with eventType so the front end can use it.

Comment: Data is in mongo db and the data is static. @bergi

Comment: the json is incorrect

Comment: Why don't you use MongoDB query then? Processing that much data can slow down the performance of your app as it runs in main thread, hand over that task to the database instead

Comment: 1. Are you missing some `{` or `}` in your example data?  2. Is `eventId` an array or really a comma separated string? As you are doing `eventList[k].eventId.includes(eventId)`, you will get incorrect result if eventId is a string.

Comment: @sujeet I have this data from legacy system from a config file, adding this data to db will also takes considerable amount of time right

Comment: @RickyMo I intentionally kept them as comma separated in order to reduce the number of limes needed as the eventType is repeated for many cases.

Comment: If you use comma separated string instead of array, then you should be doing `eventId.split(",").includes(eventId)`, otherwise `"10,2,3".includes("1")` will be true.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I will update that. But for node js logic can we use worker js to process. Adding them to db means if I have like 20 eventIds then it will be queried db 20 times. This config will be mostly static and won't be changed frequently. @RickyMo

Comment: @sujeet I also added in memory cache logic to node js such that we don't call backend db everytime.

Comment: "*Adding them to db means if I have like 20 eventIds then it will be queried db 20 times.*" - no, not if you write the query to contain all 20 eventids at once. MongoDb should be capable of doing this processing. "*This config will be mostly static*" - then you should consider building a `Map` from event ids to event types so that on every request you only need to do a simple lookup

Comment: @Bergi can you please share a sample with the map, my background is java, still trying to get to know all the stuff.

Comment: Btw, why do you have multiple `eventList`s objects, does that mean anything?

Comment: Can one `eventId` be contained in multiple different `eventList`s? In the example you gave there is a unique mapping from the event (id) to its (event) type, is that guaranteed?

Comment: EventIds are unique but if at all there are duplicate we can take which ever one first matches. Yes the event lists can be different since this is a manual json document upload to mongodb, we will add a new list. So far it was not updated for a while. But if we update we have to take care of the scenario. @Bergi

Comment: "*we can take which ever one first matches*" - then a trivial optimisation would be to break the loop once you found one, should roughly halve the execution time

Comment: @Bergi yes I did that but that doesn't improve it much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is other data in these "event lists" that you haven't shown us here, but for the task at hand (looking up event type from event id) you would want to choose a more efficient lookup structure. You definitely should store the `eventIds` in an array, not in a string (which also will lead to false matches where an event id is contained in another id). You then should consider using an appropriate MongoDB query to just fetch the event types you are looking for, passing the input ids directly to the database.

Either way, you can also do this in JS, building a lookup structure:

```
const eventTypeByEventId = new Map();
for (const {eventList} of response) {
    for (const {eventId, eventType} of eventListl) {
        for (const id of eventId.split(',')) {
            eventTypeByEventId.set(Number(id), eventType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then with that built, use

```
for (const eventId of request.eventId) {
    const eventType = eventTypeByEventId.get(eventId);
    console.log(eventType
        ? `${eventId} matches ${eventType}`
        : `${eventId} does not match`
    );
}
```

You can probably even share the `eventTypeByEventId` structure across requests if you say that it rarely changes.

Comment: this works for me, creating a map improved the performance a lot. Thanks for the suggestion. Have a nice day